# Can't log to my Ubuntu session after power failure

Tags: unity, login, session

I'm getting this error when I try to log in to my Ubuntu session:

> Your session only lasted less than 10 seconds. If you have not logged
>   out yourself, this could mean that there is some installation problem
>   or that you may be out of diskspace. Try logging in with one of the
>   failsafe sessions to see if you can fix this problem

Comment: I forgot to metion that i am running 12.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) to run this command: :

```
mv ~/.config ~/.config-old
```

Then logging out and logging back in.

Or, maybe this [post](http://pcinfo.thepebkac.net/2009/06/18/linux_error_session_10_seconds.aspx) can be helpful for you.

Comment: Not working i tried everything

Comment: @EngelsPeralta I just edited the answer, try that link.

Comment: Radu nothing yet and i really don't want to format my drive.

Comment: Well i finally fixed my ubuntu now i can log in, i was using for some time the mdm display manager so i did a sudo dpkg-reconfigure lighdm and rebooted my pc.

Comment: @EngelsPeralta If my answer was useful for you, don't forget to accept the answer and maybe vote it up