# Can't log in to Gnome session

Tags: boot, 20.04, gnome, login

**EDIT**

#### What I tried

To solve **problem #2** below

1. Logging into VT2 and running

   $ startx -- :0

(or `:1`) gives me

```
...
EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/user1/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log" for additional...
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

and

```
$ cat /home/user1/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log
...
[ 10263.352] (II) Loading /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/libglxserver_nvidia.so
[ 10263.357] (II) Module glxserver_nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[ 10263.357]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[ 10263.357]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[ 10263.357] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  470.57.02  Tue Jul 13 16:10:58 UTC 2021
[ 10263.357] (EE)
[ 10263.357] (EE) Backtrace:
[ 10263.357] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x13c) [0x55f4e294e60c]
[ 10263.357] (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (funlockfile+0x60) [0x7f9b646623c0]
[ 10263.357] (EE) 2: ? (?+0x0) [0x0]
[ 10263.357] (EE)
[ 10263.357] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[ 10263.357] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[ 10263.357] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
```

---

#### The problem(s)

Since just now, I booted (I will number this boot (`-1`)) and I cannot log into a Gnome session. I have Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
The problem: *Entering my password, flashes the screen as it would do in a normal login to display my desktop, but instead it brings me back to the login screen.*
*Login fails with any of the two users (see below), so I guess it is not something related to any of the users, that I could solve by logging in in a console and `mv ~/.config ~/.config-old` + rebooting.*

This is a timeline of what happened

```
  (A)      (B)      (C)             (D)              (E)         
  work     (-2)     some       login ok VT1    failed login VT1  
normally          tinkering     both users        both users               

      (F)           (G)              (H)
    install         (-1)   failed login VT1 + No X VT2
libnvidia-gl-470                  both users
```

and I will describe it next.

- I was working normally `(A)`, rebooted `(B) = (-2)`, and still working normally.
  I had only user `user1` that I used for everything.
- At `(C)` I created user `guest` a couple of days ago, to test something about login screens (and the failure may be related to this).
  I was logged into a gnome session with `user1` in virtual terminal VT2 (Ctrl+Alt+F2) and I could work normally.
  I could log in normally with both users in VT1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1) as well.
  I was testing killing the sessions in VT1 with `killall -3 gnome-shell` and related commands, but still did not see any problem `(D)`.
- At some point `(E)` I started seeing in VT1 the **problem #1** above. I do not know what I did in between `(D)` and `(E)`, perhaps some of the commands tested generated the problem.
- `(F)` Manually installed `sudo apt install libnvidia-470-gl`. **As far as I remember**, the problem appeared before this.
- After sleeping the PC and resuming, it was frozen, so I cold booted it `(G) = (-1)`.
  I slept / hibernated / resumed the PC a few times before, in between `(E)` and `(G)`.
- Now `(H)` VT1 has problem #1, and VT2 only gives me a console, not an X session (**problem #2**).

So I have two terribly combined problems.

**I mean to solve both.**

Solving #2 could at least make it much easier working to solve #1, within an X session in the same PC that I have the problem.

Further possibly relevant info:

1. Up until boot `(-1)`, VT2 was shown on startup, and this is my experience with all Ubuntu's I installed since a few years ago, probably all after the change of layout of X sessions / consoles). Now (the failing) VT1 is shown on startup.

#### Related

1. [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)
2. [Can't log to my Ubuntu session after power failure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295911/cant-log-to-my-ubuntu-session-after-power-failure)
3. [Can't log in to desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156962/cant-log-in-to-desktop)
4. https://www.linux.org/threads/ubuntu-wont-let-me-sign-in.26728/
5. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=185555
6. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85383/how-to-start-a-second-x-session

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: @guiverc - Not so far... there are lots of suggestions. and what works (if anything) varies widely. I am covering them.
But since I am sort of "desperate" to get going, perhaps someone could identify my specific case and help with either problem #1 or #2.
I am not lazy, and I don't see any problem with posting while I work.

Comment: Do you have space in $HOME; as it's the most common cause in my experience, unless changes were made prior session (leading to the issue), upgrades were installed last session (again leading to the issue) - ie. in my experience it's lack of disk space or the operator has a clue as to the real issue

Comment: @guiverc - No problems with disk space. >25Gb free in `/` and `/home`.

Comment: If you can get a terminal type `ls /usr/bin/*session` and update your question with the outpur. Then type `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` and reboot.

Comment: We're March 2023 and I have again encountered that issue, now with Fedora 37 too on a different Dell laptop. I had it twice with Ubuntu in December & January. Seems really related to Gnome in my opinion, not really distro dependent I'm afraid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
```